# PubNub to server data transfer

Tags: publish-subscribe, pubnub

I am building an IoT application. I am using PubNub to communicate between the harware and the user.
Now I need to store all the messages and data coming from the hardware and from the user in a central server. We want to do a bit of machine learning.

Is there a way to do this other than having the server subscribe to all the output channels (There will be a LOT of them)?

I was hoping for some kind of once-a-day data dump involving the storage and playback module in PubNub

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## PubNub to Server Data Transfer

Yes you can perform once-a-day data dumps involving the storage and playback feature.

> *But first check this out!*  You can subscribe to **Wildcard Channels** like `a.*` and `a.b.*` to receive all messages in the hierarchy below.  That way you can receive messages on all channels if you prefix each channel with a root channel like: `root.chan_1` and `root.chan_2`.  Now you can subscribe to `root.*` and receive all messages in the root.

To enable once-a-day data dumps involving Storage and Playback, first **enable [Storage and Playback](https://www.pubnub.com/products/storage-and-playback/)** on your account.  PubNub will store all your messages on disk over multiple data centers for reliability and read latency performance boost.  Lastly you can use the **[History API](https://www.pubnub.com/developers/tutorials/storage-and-playback/)** on your server to fetch all data stored as far back as forever as long as you know the channels to fetch.

Here is a JavaScript function that will fetch all messages from a channel.

### Get All Messages Usage

```
get_all_history({
    limit    : 1000,
    channel  : "my_channel_here",
    error    : function(e) { },
    callback : function(messages) {
        console.log(messages);
    }
});
```

### Get All Messages Code

```
function get_all_history(args) {
    var channel  = args['channel']
    ,   callback = args['callback']
    ,   limit    = +args['limit'] || 5000
    ,   start    = 0
    ,   count    = 100
    ,   history  = []
    ,   params   = {
            channel  : channel,
            count    : count,
            callback : function(messages) {
                var msgs = messages[0];
                start = messages[1];
                params.start = start;
                PUBNUB.each( msgs.reverse(), function(m) {history.push(m)} );
                callback(history);

                if (history.length >= limit) return;
                if (msgs.length < count)     return;

                count = 100;
                add_messages();
            },
            error : function(e) {
                log(  message_out, [ 'HISTORY ERROR', e ], '#FF2262' );
            }
        };

    add_messages();
    function add_messages() { pubnub.history(params) }
}
```